# Solve $\log_{1/3}(x^2-3x+3)≥0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, logarithms

I want to solve $$\log_{1/3}(x^2-3x+3)≥0$$
Now I know the result is: $x ∈ <1;2>$, but i am not sure how to get it.

My thoughts: $\frac{1}{3}$ to the power of positive number $= (x^2-3x+3)$, now I would solve $x^2-3x+3$ with the help of discriminant to get the points where $x$ is zero, and say the answer is for the positive intervals. Is this correct / is there easier way to do it?

Comment: Hint: $\log_a(t)=\ln(t)/\ln(a)$ hence $\ln_a(t)\ge0$ if and only if $\ln(t)=0$ or $\ln(t)$ has the sign of $\ln(a)$. In the present case, $\ln(a)$ is $______$ hence...

Comment: I think it should be $x^2$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar you are correct, I don't know how that happened, sorry.

Comment: It is productive to actually draw the graph of $y=(1/3)^t$, and then use that graph to draw a graph of $y=\log_{1/3} t$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\log_{1/3}(x^2-3x+3) \ge 0$$

This occurs when:

$$x^2-3x+3 \le 1$$
$$x^2-3x+2 \le 0$$

Factorizing, we get:

$$(x-1)(x-2) \le 0$$

Solving the inequality, we get:

$$1 \le x \le 2$$

**ALTERNATE SOLUTION**

Consider the following equation:

$$\log_{1/3}(x^2-3x+3) = 0$$

If we solve, we get:

$$x^2 -3x + 2 = 0$$
$$(x-1)(x-2) = 0$$

Now, if we have $x < 1$, $x^2 - 3x + 3 \ge 1$

This means that a possible value is $\log_{1/3}5$, which would a value **less than** $0$.

Similarly if $x > 2$, $x^2 - 3x + 3 \ge 1$.

When $1 < x < 2$, we have that $0 < x^2 - 3x + 3 < 1$, meaning only fractional answers exist.

This means that a possible value is $\log_{1/3}\frac{1}{3}$, which would a value **greater than** $0$.

Comment: how did you determine, that the sign (>) should be flipped in the second step? ($x^2-3x+3 \le 1$)?

Comment: $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^x$ is a decreasing function.

Comment: so if it was for example $(3)^x$ we wouldn't flip the sign, right?

Comment: @Mykybo consider my alternate solution I added to my answer. Hopefully it might help you understand the solution in a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

Raise $\frac{1}{3}$ to the power of both sides, and flip the inequality because $\frac{1}{3}^x$ is a decreasing function:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\log_{1/3}(x^2 - 3x + 3 ) &≥ 0\\
x^2 - 3x + 3 &\le \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^0\\
x^2 - 3x + 3 &\le 1\\
x^2 - 3x + 2 &\le 0\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Now factor to get $(x-1)(x-2) \le 0$. We need a negative and a positive sign to make a negative, hence

$$1 \le x \le 2$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint when we solve log the inequality gets reversed thus our problem on simplifying becomes $x^2-3x+2<=0$ so $(x-1)(x-2)<=0$ thus using general wavy curve method $1<=x<=2$ its done.

Comment: Haha, "general wavy curve method!"

Comment: Is it called something else

Comment: Not that I can think of! I like this name :)

Answer (score 0):

Passing to neperian logarithms we have $$\frac{\ln(x^2-3x+3)}{\ln(\frac 13)}$$ Therefore since $\ln(\frac 13)<0$ we need to have $\ln(x^2-3x+3)\le0$. This happens when $x^2-3x+3= 1$ which give $(x-2)(x-1)=0$ $x=1$ and $x=2$ Thus
$$1\le x\le 2$$